# Syndesis (Fuse-online) Integration build failed for unknown host "maven1.repo.org"

Tags: kubernetes, syndesis

We installed fuse-online 7.4 on openshift 3.11. We created an integration containing an OpenApiProvider connection and an SQL connection.

When we publish the integration, the build fails with the following error:
"repo1.maven.org: Name or service not known: Unknown host repo1.maven.org: Name or service not known"

- Openshift is installed behing an enterprise http proxy
- The image registry.access.redhat.com/fuse7/fuse-ignite-s2i is pulled correctly since docker is configured with proxy.
- syndesis-server DeploymentConfig has been set with proxies environment variables

I suppose that, since the buildconfig for the integration is created dynamically, is not possible to inject HTTP_PROXY,HTTPS_PROXY,NO_PROXY env variables to the build pod.

We read https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/http_proxies.html#s2i-builds but since we don't have any rights to modify s2i image we cannot proceed.

Is there any  way to provide proxy information during during fuse-online integration build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally we succeeded to inject http proxy environment variables in dynamic created build pods.
We modified syndesis-server-config config map reporting proxy variables on mavenOptions key like this:

mavenOptions: "-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -Xmx310m -Dhttp.proxyHost= -Dhttp.proxyPort= -Dhttps.proxyHost= -Dhttps.proxyPort= -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="

Thanks for the support

Let me know if you have any other idea of resolving the issue

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the DNS of your network connection? Not sure why but sometimes I have to use one of the "reliable" DNS on my machine (like the 8.8.8.8 from Google) to make sure repo1.maven.org is reachable.

You can check if this is the problem trying a simple

```
$ ping repo1.maven.org
```

If that doesn't work, you have to check your DNS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually the dns configured on openshift nodes just resolve local addresses. 
In order to reach external services i need to use enterprise http proxy, that's why i would try to inject proxy env variables in build configuration resource.